# ASP.NET Owin Identity Override Password Generation

Tags: c#, asp.net, encryption, asp.net-identity, owin

I'm using ASP.NET identity OWIN for user authentication in my website. The default library from .Net hashes passwords and stores them in the ASPNETUSERS table when a user is created. I want to override the password generation process and encrypt the password with my custom encryption classes. The reason I want to do it, is I want to be able to decrypt passwords once they're stored in my table. I assume I would also need to override something for the user login, so it can encrypt the password and compare it accordingly. Can you point me in the right direction about which method to override, or which interface/class to override to achieve this? Or if there is another way of doing it?

Comment: That is such a bad idea i dont know where to start. But as a base the owner of the service/site/DB/whatever should never have the means to read a password, if he can (and he will get hacked) the hacker can. The password is the secret the client knows and the username is the information both knows. (in these matters the secret MUST be secret as much of the time as possible (where possible is the keyword)) (your service will be entrusted with the secret, expecting you to throw it away at once you have validated the user)

Comment: I guess you make a good point, I'll keep hashing them instead and just send a create password token.

Comment: That is what you are supposed to do. Its best practice

Answer (score 3):

Ideally, you want to use hash *(one-way encryption)* algorithm for password. Well, if you really want to encrypt it, you can assign CustomPasswordHasher to **UserManager** instance.

```
_userManager = HttpContext.GetOwinContext().GetUserManager<ApplicationUserManager>();
_userManager.PasswordHasher = new CustomPasswordHasher();
```

### Implementation

```
public class CustomPasswordHasher : IPasswordHasher
{
    public string HashPassword(string password)
    {
        // Custom encrypted password
    }

    public PasswordVerificationResult VerifyHashedPassword(
        string hashedPassword, string providedPassword)
    {
        if (hashedPassword.Equals(providedPassword))
            return PasswordVerificationResult.Success;
        return PasswordVerificationResult.Failed;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could simply use your own validation methods for the password and use [SignInManager.SignInAsync](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt173757(v=vs.108).aspx) after you validate the given password. But as Thomas said, you should not be able to decrypt passwords.